# Spirit.X3: passing local data to a parser

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

The examples in the Boost.Spirit documentation seem to fall in two cases:

1/ Define a parser in a function: semantic actions can access local variables and data as they are local lambdas. Like `push_back` here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/number_list___stuffing_numbers_into_a_std__vector.html

2/ Define a parser in a namespace, like here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/minimal.html

which seems to be necessary to be able to invoke `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE`.

My question is: how to combine both (properly, without globals) ? My dream API would be to pass some argument to `phrase_parse` and then do some `x3::_arg(ctx)` but I couldn't find anything like this.

Here is for instance my parser: for now the actions are writing to `std::cerr`. What if I wanted to write to a custom `std::ostream&` instead, that would be passed to the `parse` function?

```cpp
using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

rule<struct id_action> action = "action";
rule<struct id_array> array = "array";
rule<struct id_empty_array> empty_array = "empty_array";
rule<struct id_atom> atom = "atom";
rule<struct id_sequence> sequence = "sequence";
rule<struct id_root> root = "root";

auto access_index_array = [] (const auto& ctx) { std::cerr << "access_array: " << x3::_attr(ctx) << "\n" ;};
auto access_empty_array = [] (const auto& ctx) { std::cerr << "access_empty_array\n" ;};
auto access_named_member = [] (const auto& ctx) { std::cerr << "access_named_member: " << x3::_attr(ctx) << "\n" ;};
auto start_action = [] (const auto& ctx) { std::cerr << "start action\n" ;};
auto finish_action = [] (const auto& ctx) { std::cerr << "finish action\n" ;};
auto create_array = [] (const auto& ctx) { std::cerr << "create_array\n" ;};

const auto action_def = +(lit('.')[start_action]
                      >> -((+alnum)[access_named_member])
                      >> *(('[' >> x3::int_ >> ']')[access_index_array] | lit("[]")[access_empty_array]));
const auto sequence_def = (action[finish_action] % '|');
const auto array_def = ('[' >> sequence >> ']')[create_array];
const auto root_def = array | action;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(action)
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(array)
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(sequence)
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(root)

bool parse(std::string_view str)
{
  using ascii::space;
  auto first = str.begin();
  auto last = str.end();
  bool r = phrase_parse(
             first, last,
             parser::array_def | parser::sequence_def,
             ascii::space
  );

  if (first != last)
    return false;
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the approaches:

1/ Yes, this is viable for small, contained parsers. Typically only used in a single TU, and exposed via non-generic interface.

2/ This is the approach for (much) larger grammars, that you might wish to spread across TUs, and/or are instantiated across several TU's generically.

Note that you do NOT need `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE` unless  you

- have recursive rules
- want to split declaration from definition. [This becomes pretty complicated, and I recommend against using that for X3.]

### The Question

> My question is: how to combine both (properly, without globals) ?

You can't combine something with namespace level declarations, if one of the requiremenents is "without globals".

> My dream API would be to pass some argument to phrase_parse and then do some x3::_arg(ctx) but I couldn't find anything like this.

I don't know what you think `x3::_arg(ctx)` would do, in that particular dream :)

> Here is for instance my parser: for now the actions are writing to std::cerr. What if I wanted to write to a custom std::ostream& instead, that would be passed to the parse function?

Now that's a concrete question. I'd say: use the context.

You could make it so that you can use `x3::get<ostream>(ctx)` returns the stream:

```
struct ostream{};

auto access_index_array  = [] (const auto& ctx) { x3::get<ostream>(ctx) << "access_array: " << x3::_attr(ctx) << "\n" ;};
auto access_empty_array  = [] (const auto& ctx) { x3::get<ostream>(ctx) << "access_empty_array\n" ;};
auto access_named_member = [] (const auto& ctx) { x3::get<ostream>(ctx) << "access_named_member: " <<  x3::_attr(ctx) << "\n" ;};
auto start_action        = [] (const auto& ctx) { x3::get<ostream>(ctx) << "start action\n" ;};
auto finish_action       = [] (const auto& ctx) { x3::get<ostream>(ctx) << "finish action\n" ;};
auto create_array        = [] (const auto& ctx) { x3::get<ostream>(ctx) << "create_array\n";};
```

Now you need to put the tagged param in the context during parsing:

```
bool r = phrase_parse(
    f, l,
    x3::with<parser::ostream>(std::cerr)[parser::array_def | parser::sequence_def],
    x3::space);
```

Live Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a26c8eb0af6370b9

Prints

```
start action
access_named_member: a
finish action
start action
access_named_member: b
start action
start action
access_array: 2
start action
access_named_member: foo
start action
access_empty_array
finish action
start action
access_named_member: c
finish action
create_array
true
```

Intermixed with the standard X3 debug output:

```
<sequence>
  <try>.a|.b..[2].foo.[]|.c</try>
  <action>
    <try>.a|.b..[2].foo.[]|.c</try>
    <success>|.b..[2].foo.[]|.c]</success>
  </action>
  <action>
    <try>.b..[2].foo.[]|.c]</try>
    <success>|.c]</success>
  </action>
  <action>
    <try>.c]</try>
    <success>]</success>
  </action>
  <success>]</success>
</sequence>
```

### But Wait #1 - Event Handlers

It looks like you're parsing something similar to JSON Pointer or `jq` syntax. In the case that you wanted to provide a callback-interface (SAX-events), why not bind the callback interface instead of the actions:

```
struct handlers {
    using N = x3::unused_type;
    virtual void index(int) {}
    virtual void index(N) {}
    virtual void property(std::string) {}
    virtual void start(N) {}
    virtual void finish(N) {}
    virtual void create_array(N) {}
};

#define EVENT(e) ([](auto& ctx) { x3::get<handlers>(ctx).e(x3::_attr(ctx)); })

const auto action_def =
    +(x3::lit('.')[EVENT(start)] >> -((+x3::alnum)[EVENT(property)]) >>
      *(('[' >> x3::int_ >> ']')[EVENT(index)] | x3::lit("[]")[EVENT(index)]));

const auto sequence_def = action[EVENT(finish)] % '|';
const auto array_def    = ('[' >> sequence >> ']')[EVENT(create_array)];
const auto root_def     = array | action;
```

Now you can implement all handlers neatly in one interface:

```
struct default_handlers : parser::handlers {
    std::ostream& os;
    default_handlers(std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}

    void index(int i) override            { os << "access_array: " << i << "\n";          };
    void index(N) override                { os << "access_empty_array\n" ;                };
    void property(std::string n) override { os << "access_named_member: " <<  n << "\n" ; };
    void start(N) override                { os << "start action\n" ;                      };
    void finish(N) override               { os << "finish action\n" ;                     };
    void create_array(N) override         { os << "create_array\n";                       };
};

auto f = str.begin(), l = str.end();
bool r = phrase_parse(f, l,
                      x3::with<parser::handlers>(default_handlers{std::cout}) //
                          [parser::array_def | parser::sequence_def],
                      x3::space);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a983e762a8a2afbf)** once again:

```
start action
access_named_member: a
finish action
start action
access_named_member: b
start action
start action
access_array: 2
start action
access_named_member: foo
start action
access_empty_array
finish action
start action
access_named_member: c
finish action
create_array
true
```

### But Wait #2 - No Actions

The natural way to expose attributes would be to build an AST. See also [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Without further ado:

```
namespace AST {
    using Id = std::string;
    using Index = int;
    struct Member {
        std::optional<Id> name;
    };
    struct Indexer {
        std::optional<int> index;
    };
    struct Action {
        Member member;
        std::vector<Indexer> indexers;
    };

    using Actions = std::vector<Action>;
    using Sequence = std::vector<Actions>;

    struct ArrayCtor {
        Sequence actions;
    };

    using Root = boost::variant<ArrayCtor, Actions>;
}
```

Of course, I'm making some assumptions. The rules can be much simplified:

```
namespace parser {
    template <typename> struct Tag {};
    #define AS(T, p) (x3::rule<Tag<AST::T>, AST::T>{#T} = p)

    auto id       = AS(Id, +x3::alnum);
    auto member   = AS(Member, x3::lit('.') >> -id);
    auto indexer  = AS(Indexer,'[' >> -x3::int_ >> ']');

    auto action   = AS(Action, member >> *indexer);
    auto actions  = AS(Actions, +action);

    auto sequence = AS(Sequence, actions % '|');
    auto array    = AS(ArrayCtor, '[' >> -sequence >> ']'); // covers empty array
    auto root     = AS(Root, array | actions);
} // namespace parser
```

And the parsing function returns the AST:

```
AST::Root parse(std::string_view str) {
    auto f = str.begin(), l = str.end();

    AST::Root parsed;
    phrase_parse(f, l, x3::expect[parser::root >> x3::eoi], x3::space, parsed);

    return parsed;
}
```

(Note that it now throws `x3::expection_failure` if the input is invalid or not completely parsed)

```
int main() {
    std::cout << parse("[.a|.b..[2].foo.[]|.c]");
}
```

Now prints:

```
[.a|.b./*none*/./*none*/[2].foo./*none*/[/*none*/]|.c]
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16d83340d407dabc)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <ostream>
#include <optional>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace AST {
    using Id = std::string;
    using Index = int;
    struct Member {
        std::optional<Id> name;
    };
    struct Indexer {
        std::optional<int> index;
    };
    struct Action {
        Member member;
        std::vector<Indexer> indexers;
    };

    using Actions = std::vector<Action>;
    using Sequence = std::vector<Actions>;

    struct ArrayCtor {
        Sequence actions;
    };

    using Root = boost::variant<ArrayCtor, Actions>;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::Member, name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::Indexer, index)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::Action, member, indexers)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::ArrayCtor, actions)

namespace parser {
    template <typename> struct Tag {};
    #define AS(T, p) (x3::rule<Tag<AST::T>, AST::T>{#T} = p)

    auto id       = AS(Id, +x3::alnum);
    auto member   = AS(Member, x3::lit('.') >> -id);
    auto indexer  = AS(Indexer,'[' >> -x3::int_ >> ']');

    auto action   = AS(Action, member >> *indexer);
    auto actions  = AS(Actions, +action);

    auto sequence = AS(Sequence, actions % '|');
    auto array    = AS(ArrayCtor, '[' >> -sequence >> ']'); // covers empty array
    auto root     = AS(Root, array | actions);
} // namespace parser

AST::Root parse(std::string_view str) {
    auto f = str.begin(), l = str.end();

    AST::Root parsed;
    phrase_parse(f, l, x3::expect[parser::root >> x3::eoi], x3::space, parsed);

    return parsed;
}

// for debug output
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
namespace AST {
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Member const& m) {
        return os << "." << m.name.value_or("/*none*/");
    }

    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Indexer const& i) {
        if (i.index)
            return os << "[" << *i.index << "]";
        else
            return os << "[/*none*/]";
    }

    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Action const& a) {
        os << a.member;
        for (auto& i : a.indexers)
            os << i;
        return os;
    }

    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Actions const& aa) {
        for (auto& a : aa)
            os << a;
        return os;
    }

    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sequence const& s) {
        bool first = true;
        for (auto& a : s)
            os << (std::exchange(first, false) ? "" : "|") << a;
        return os;
    }

    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ArrayCtor const& ac) {
        return os << "[" << ac.actions << "]";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << parse("[.a|.b..[2].foo.[]|.c]");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer, reading. And indeed, I'm making a jq-ish thing :)

Comment: It just became more complete: an AST based parser: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16d83340d407dabc

Comment: @sehe "Note that you do NOT need BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE unless you [...]". Now I am doubting everything I learned from the x3 tutorials... :'-) Do you mean that the tutorials are intentionally using overkilled stuff such as BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE although the declaration and the definition are not clearly separated in their examples, in order to show to the newbies the power of x3 ? Or did I simply misunderstand sthg ?

Comment: @PlayerK something like that, but probably in reverse: They show the full dance so you get less confused when things don't compile when you actually need e.g. recursion.